# Put divs like rulers on left and top w/jsfiddle.net

Tags: html, css, html5-canvas

I have a problem implementing this schema:
[image]

Here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ptCoder/3WB32/

The "Bar 2" need to be rotate in vertical:

```
transform: rotate(90deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(90deg); /* IE 9 */
-webkit-transform: rotate(90deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
```

Can anyone help me?

Thank You.

Comment: You have referred to your divs as classes in your CSS not ID's.

Comment: Thank you. I made a mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could fudge something like this together DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/3WB32/5/

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="hbar">Bar 1</div>
    <div id="vbar">Bar 2</div>
    <canvas id="c" width="400px" height="400px">CANVAS</canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: WOW. Thank You very much. How do you have calculated the margin in vbar? ( margin:173px 0 0 -168px;)

Comment: Changing the value until the desired result is reached.

Answer (score 1):

Below is a custom approach I've built, it personally makes more sense to me to do it this way. You can see how it functions / looks by clicking on the example on the bottom.

**The HTML:**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="bar-1">
        <p>Bar 1</p>
    </div>
    <div id="bar-2">
        <p>Bar 2</p>
    </div>
    <div id="canvas">
        This is the canvas
    </div>
</div>
```

**The CSS:**

```
#wrapper{
    min-height: 500px;
    position: relative;
    background: #ccc;
}
#bar-1{
    position: absolute;
    left: 100px;
    right: 100px;
    background: blue;
    height: 100px;
}
#bar-2{
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    background: red;
    bottom: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}
#canvas{
    position: absolute;
    top:100px;
    left: 100px;
    background: yellow;
    bottom: 100px;
    right: 100px;

}
```

[**Click here for a working example of the above code:**](http://jsfiddle.net/yBYP4/5/)

Comment: what do you mean *be rotate in vertical* ?

Comment: If you have a div in horizontal and need to rotate to vertical position. Please check this: http://jsfiddle.net/3WB32/4/

Answer (score 1):

You are giving same class to both div

```
<div id="hbar" class="hbar">Bar 1</div>
<div id="vbar" class="hbar">Bar 2</div>
```

change second one to `vbar`

Comment: I have tried something. you need to do some workaround with this http://jsfiddle.net/3WB32/4/